# How does counter update work in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I was reading about counters. Then I wanted to know when to use INT vs COUNTER. I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412377/counter-vs-int-column-in-cassandra)

Now, I understand when to use it and what it does. But my question here is "How counter works without read before write and locking" in distributed environment.

Comment: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters, http://rockthecode.io/blog/highly-available-counters-using-cassandra/

Comment: i really like https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters description too